# how to minus/divide between <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> and <class 'method'> with <bound method Series.mean>?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We would like to calculate with both `pandas.series` data and `bound method series` data, how to minus/divide between <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> and <class 'method'> with ? They are all with the same format like below:

```
1         0.582371
2         0.582605
3         0.582605
4         0.612935
             ...   
999       0.223501
1000      0.177610
```

Comment: if both operands **have the same length** you can just use `+` and `-`, if not then it's unclear what the result should be.

Comment: The different class type will get `TypeError: <class 'method'>`

Comment: I guess without a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) you won't get any answer here.